# how to solve vectors in 3D?

Tags: vector-spaces

[image: this is the question in our exam]

We had our examination a few days ago. I was not able to answer this question. So I decided to remember it and answer at home but still I can't answer this on my own.

Please help me to answer this so that if this type of question will be asked again in our incoming major exam, I can answer it.

Comment: What you have here is a [scalar triple product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product). You can either do it all manually or you can recognize this corresponds to the *signed* volume of the parallelepiped with edges $D,H,F$ and compute it another way (pay attention to sign).

Comment: how to do it? i have an idea that this can be solved via rectangular components (as a read once in a book). but i can't apply it.. how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First use trigonometry to find the x, y and z components of each vector.

Comment: how to use trigonometry to find the x y and z components? this is also my idea but i don't know how to apply it. please explain. thank you.

Comment: For D this shouldn't be too hard- draw a vertical line down from the end of the vector to the x-axis and you have a right angled triangle. For the other two, the dashed triangles are right angled and so you can split the vector into a component in the z-direction and a component in the xy plane. Then for the component in the xy plane, just do the same as with the D vector

Comment: sir can you send me an attachment or file on how you split the two vectors into z-direction and into xy plane? this technique was not teached to us so i have no idea how to split the vector. i am not wanting the final answer, i want is how to find the final answer by using the technique you said so please show me how was it done. thank you.

Comment: Using F as an example, the green vector and the two dashed lines form a right angle triangle. You can see that one dashed line is purely in the z-direction while the other lies in the xy plane. In the plane this triangle lies in, you can see that the vector is at an angle of 60 degrees to the z-axis and hence the angle between the vector and the xy plane (which lies inside the right angle triangle) is 30 degrees. So the z component will be $F sin(30)$ while the component in the xy plane will be $F cos(30)$

Comment: sir thank you for your answer. it is now clearer to me than before. is it okay to you that i would ask you few more question? such as what would be the unit vector of the component in xy plane? the fsin30 have its unit vector k. also, what does 45 degrees doing on the figure since we have the components of F using only the 30 degrees of z-axis? thanks.

Comment: you still need to resolve the component in the xy plane into a component purely in the x direction and one purely in the y direction. The 45 degrees is the angle between the component of F in the xy plane and the x-axis (note this now looks like the situation for the D vector)

Comment: so the component for F would be Fsin30k + Fcos45i + Fsin45j instead of Fsin30k + Fcos30? is that right for F sir? thank you.

Comment: very close but you've got to include that the magnitude of the component of $\textbf{F}$ in the xy plane is no longer $F$ but $F cos(30)$ so it will be $F cos(30) cos(45) \textbf{i} + F cos(30) sin(45) \textbf{j} + F sin(30) \textbf{k}$

Comment: sir, why would i distribute the F cos (30) [the component of dashed line that lies to the x-y plane] into the F cos (45)i + F sin (45)j [the resolve component of that on the x-y plane]. thank you sir

Comment: because the 45 degrees is only the angle between the axis and the component of $\textbf{F}$ in the xy plane therefore when we find the x and y components using sin(45) and cos(45) we're only finding them based off the component of $\textbf{F}$ in the xy plane and this component only had magnitude $F cos (30)$

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9023/discussion-between-nicy12-and-john)

Comment: whoa! thanks sir! you are really a genius! i understand this even clearer! thank you sir! now, i am ready to answer this question. i will tell you my answer and please verify if i got the correct one. thank so much sir for your help! :)

Comment: You're very welcome!

Comment: ahmm sir, is it right that the component of vector H is 0 i- H cos60 cos37 j +(Hsin60+Hcos60sin37)k ?

Comment: you are close but have made a couple of mistakes. Try breaking the problem into parts like we did before.
First into a component in the z direction and one in the xy plane. You should now be finished finding the component in the z (or $\textbf{k}$) direction). Then it's almost like you're starting a new problem with finding the components of the component in the xy plane in the x and y directions.

Comment: ahmm sir, that was i did. i started solving vector H, just the component of vector H.i started splitting the vector H into a component in the z-direction and a component in the y-z plane.the component of the dashed line that is purely z-direction is H sin 60 k.then the dashed line that lies to the y-z plane, i break it into purely y-direction and z-direction which is -H cos 60 cos 37 j and H cos 60 sin 37 respectively. i combined the two k unit vector. so i came up to 0 i - H cos 60 cos 37 j + (H sin 60 + H cos 60 sin 37) k. thank you sir.

Comment: ahhh. You have exactly the right method then but the other component is in the xy plane, not the yz plane. It takes a bit of time to get used to interpreting 3D diagrams.

Comment: ohh.. suppose that i used to know interpreting 3D diagrams better than now, the component of vector H would be H cos 60 sin 37 i - H cos 60 cos 37 j + H sin 60 k. is it right sir? thanks.

Comment: Very, very close but be careful about which one is sin and which is cos as well as which are positive and which are negative

Comment: ahmm sir, sorry if i failed to fully understand this topic. the only change that i can provide to my answer is -H cos 60 sin 37 i -H cos 60 cos 37 j + H sin 60 k. if this answer is still wrong, please tell me the correct one and the reason behind that answer. thank you so much sir for your dedication to teach me. thanks a lot.

Comment: That's correct!

Comment: whoaa! really sir!? is it true!? the only thing i missed on my answer above is the -H in i instead of H? hehe sorry sir if i got confused by you said that i should be careful which one is sin and which one is cos. i thought the error i have was caused by altrenating sin to cos. i really tried over and over again just to figure out what my error is and i came up with the change in sign. thank you for your effort sir to make this topic clear to me! thank you so much! it is easy to find the final answer now because all the components are provided. thank you sir! :D

Comment: no problem at all

Comment: so D x H = 208.53 i + 276.60 j - 55.12 k ?

Comment: the i and j components are correct (well technically there are some rounding errors but otherwise fine) but you need to check the k component

Comment: yes sir. i have made 4 trials and all of them showed my error in k component. my final answer for D x H will be 208.53 i + 276.60 j + 200.08 k . and the F dot (D x H) will be equal to 3969.39 . is it right sir? thanks.

Comment: You have some rounding errors that end up becoming significant but I believe you have performed the method correctly.

Comment: thank you sir! thank you so much! so you are saying that beside the rounding error, my final answer for F dot (D x H) was correct? (or maybe the whole number of final answer is correct?). thank you sir.

Comment: Yes, I get the actual answer to be 3987.13 but I am quite confident this is because of some early rounding you may have done.

Comment: ahmm sir, there is a large discrepancy on our answer.. it proved me  that my answer is acceptable but still wrong. can you teach me how to round off properly? i am always rounding off to the hundredths of decimal. thanks sir.

Comment: the problem with this is hat the numbers you were multiplying in the end were the size of hundreds so when you multiply these by numbers that are off by hundredths (actually larger at this stage), the small rounding error start getting bigger. Rather than thinking of decimal places, you should think about significant figures. If you round a number to only three significant figures, the final answer will probably only be right to at most three significant figures as a rough rule

Comment: ahmm sir i tried to resolve it again by rounding off into significant figures and i came up to an answer of 3975.4 . hehe the discrepancy gets lower :) i think i should practice more rounding off by significant figures since i am not used to it so i might be wrong in getting the exact significant figures so that i did not get the same answer as you. but more importantly, thank you very much for helping me to understand this topic fully. thank you very much sir and God Bless You! :D

Comment: No problem at all!